# Relationship between I2C operating frequency and sample rate setting in MPU6050

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gyroscope, i2c

I am interested in reading gyroscope data by RaspberryPi and Python but I am confused about how to set sample rate of the MPU6050 (accelerometer, gyroscope;[datasheet MPU6050](http://www.invensense.com/mems/gyro/documents/PS-MPU-6000A-00v3.4.pdf)) according to I2C clock frequency in order to avoid wrong reading data (for example reading while there is not data in the buffer or reading faster that writing, and so on), in the knowledge that each measure is a 16 bit word.

Is there a relationship between the two clocks?

Comment: I failed to locate the actual data registers in that datasheet. Am I blind?

Comment: I am sorry, I forget the link of [the Register Map](http://www.invensense.com/mems/gyro/documents/RM-MPU-6000A-00v4.2.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I did a project with that same chip about 18 months ago. I haven't touched the PI since then, so I don't know how things may have changed in the meantime. In any event, I used the smbus to read the chip. A few things I found out the hard way, reading individual registers was very slow compared to the i2c block read. Also, you had to turn off sleep mode. Sorry I don't have any info on the clock timing, but if you are just trying to get a good read loop, this might help. You don't have to use numpy, but if you plan to manipulate your samples, it's quite helpful. GL/HF.

```
import smbus
import numpy
# initialize
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
# turn off sleep mode
bus.write_byte_data(0x68,0x6B,0x00)

# reading in data (this can be in a loop or function call)
sample = numpy.empty(7)
r = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x68, 0x3B, 14)
sample[0] = (r[0]<<8)+r[1]
sample[1] = (r[2]<<8)+r[3]
sample[2] = (r[4]<<8)+r[5]
sample[3] = (r[6]<<8)+r[7]
sample[4] = (r[8]<<8)+r[9]
sample[5] = (r[10]<<8)+r[11]
sample[6] = (r[12]<<8)+r[13]
```

Comment: Could it be the same with: `r_H = bus.read_byte_data(0x68, 0x3B)` , `r_L = read_byte_data(0x68, 0x3C)` and then `sample = (r_H<<8) + r_L` ?

Comment: Yes.. if that's the only one you need. But if you need to get the other values, you should stick with block read. It's seriously faster. Just a tiny fraction slower than a single read IIRC.

Comment: Let's see if I have understood: With `bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x68, 0x3B, 14)` I read in a single shot accelerometer, temperature and gyro, right?

Comment: Exactly. You may not need the temperature, but it's in the middle and it's faster just to do a single block call.

Comment: Ok, it's like the C++ function [getMotion6()](http://www.i2cdevlib.com/docs/html/class_m_p_u6050.html#a574d3093dc131e4251a9b37adf208ca7). Just a question: if I may need to read at the same writing data sample rate (eg: 8kHz), can I set `time.sleep(1/8000.0)` or must it be setted at a lesser value?

Comment: You'll have to do some testing. I had my samples pegged to 100 Hz because it was all I needed. I would sleep the difference using calls to `time.time()` to record the sampling duration and processing time. Not sure if you'll be swinging >8khz sample rate using python on a rasPi. But if you do, just sleep the remainder. Again, it depends on what you need.

Comment: I have read there is an interrupt (according to map register) called DATA_RDY_EN (pag. 27 in the register map) that goes to 1 when write operation to all of the sensor registers has been completed, therefore I was thinking to use `time.sleep(1/2*fs)` in a while loop to read this interrupt and to use an `if` for reading only when `DATA_RDY_EN = True`. In this way I can be sure that samples are got when they are availabe. What do you think about it?

Comment: Honestly I doubt you will need any of that. It's unlikely python on a rPi will be able to sample fast enough to need to wait for data ready. I suspect you will have the opposite problem. Not sure that linux on a rPi can provide microsecond fidelity to `time.sleep()` even if you could run that fast. Test it first. Just read in a loop, do some 1000 read loops to guage your data rate. If you get some failed reads, you can always wrap the read in a try statement.